# How to start iterableDiffer only after OnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My problem is that the iterableDiffer detect a change when I only what to inialize the data from the database. I dont want to get this first change detection. I only want to get a change detection when the user edits the array.

I tryed to put the database request in the constructor. Didnt change anything.

```js
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private StoreService: StoreService,
    private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers
  ) {
     this.iterableDiffer = 
       this.iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
  }

  myArray: MyClass[] = [];

  iterableDiffer: IterableDiffer<unknown>;

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.StoreService.getData(id)
       .subscribe(data => this.myArray = data);
    // on this subscribe, the Differ falsely gets triggered
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    const changes = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.myArray);
    if (changes) {
      changes.forEachAddedItem((record: IterableChangeRecord<MyClass>) => {

        console.log('Added Changes detected');

        this.StoreService.addToDatabase(record.item);
      });
    }
  }

  // gets called by User Click, here i want to have the Differ called
  // This works fine
  addElmt(elmt: MyClass) {
    this.myArray.push(elmt);
  }
```

The code snippet is a simplified version of the real code. I can not call the `StoreService.addToDatabase()` in the function `addElmt()`. This is just for better explanation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why not subscribe in ngAfterViewChecked?

Comment: i dont want to load data from the Api/Database, everytime something in the component changes. Or which subscribe do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I think that was ngAfterViewInit -not your ngAfterViewChanges-

Comment: @Eliseo no, doesnt change anything. And I dont really know, what you want to achieve with this, i dont see any context to my problem

Comment: put in ngAfterViewChanges and store in a variable the OBservable, so you only subscribe if this variable is null

Answer (score 0):

Always can has a variable 'myObserver' and do

```
myObserver:any=null
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    const changes = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.myArray);
    if (changes) {
      changes.forEachAddedItem((record: IterableChangeRecord<MyClass>) => {

        console.log('Added Changes detected');

        this.StoreService.addToDatabase(record.item);
      });
    }
    if (!myObserver)
    {
      const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
      myObserver=this.StoreService.getData(id)
         .subscribe(data => this.myArray = data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doenst help my problem. :/ I added an if statement in the change detection, not very beautiful but works